# localhost/silex/web/hello To localhost/silex/hello

Tags: php, .htaccess, silex

So I just started working with Silex
and I have this code in index.php in web folder :

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app ['debug'] = true;
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/../views',
));
$app->get('/hello/', function() use($app) {
return 'Hello ';
});

$app->run();
```

which goes to : **localhost/silex/web/hello**

I don't want my links to have /web/ in them , for example I want the above link to be **localhost/silex/hello**

this is my .htaccess *(it is in the root , not in the web folder)* :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That rewriting rule obviously rewrites every request to the `index.php` file. It does not sounds like you want to do that. So why don't you change it to the path you want? Or, if there is a router in the `index.php` file, then you have to modify that instead. A task we can hardly help with, since you did not post that code.

Comment: Hi arkascha , I edited my question , the code is in an index.php in web folder , I used the information in the Silex documentation : http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html

Comment: The official documentation is if the *index.php* file is on the web root folder. Yours is not. You'll probably have to change your rewrite rule to ```RewriteRule ^ web/index.php``` (I'm not very fluent in rewrite rules so, give it a try). Be aware that your entire application you'll be reachable from the internet probably, not just the front controller (index.php).

Comment: that rewrite rule caused an internal server error..
Ok, I moved the index.php from web folder outside to the root
and changed the upper code to this :
    `<?php`
    `require_once __DIR__.'../vendor/autoload.php';`

    `$app = new Silex\Application();`
    `$app ['debug'] = true;`
    `$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(`
    `'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/views',`
    `));`
and it gave me what I wanted , but I guess there is a reason why web folder exist .. I'm sure there is a way to do this..